# Converting a string to an integer with a ternary operator

Tags: java, syntax, ternary-operator

I have a string that I would like to convert into an integer before storing it as a property of an object.  Although I can use regular if statements, I wanted to use a ternary operation to build my understanding of it.  Here is the code I've tried

```
        field_num = (((boolean bool_is_int = is_integer(string)) == true) ? (Integer int = Integer.parseInt(string)) : null);
```

What I'm trying to do (very basically) is set "field_num" (which is of type `int`) to the value of "string" if it is equal to an integer (by first converting it).  `is_integer` is a function I have to check if a string is equal to an integer. It returns a boolean value.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't pass a null to an int. Your false branch of the ternary should still be an int, possibly a flag to indicate bad input like -1 or something.

Comment: `int` is a reserved word and cannot be used for variable names http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: We've figured out (below) that field_num is probably an Integer. That would explain the null. It would have helped if that had been included in the problem statement.

Comment: keshlam: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I though I did say that. I said: "...is set 'field_num' (which is of type int)".

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
Integer theint = is_integer(thestr) ? Integer.parseInt(thstr) : null;
```

You cannot assign NULL to an intrinsic int but you can to an Integer object.  Typically, of course, you'd simply rely on the parseInt() call throwing an exception rather than explicitly testing for integerness of the string beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
field_num = is_integer(string) ? Integer.parseInt(string): -1;
```

In plain english this says if 'string' is an integer then parse string for the int and set it to field_num otherwise, set it to -1. -1 is arbitrary. you should instead use a number that is invalid for field_num.

You do not need is_integer(string) == true because that evaluates to the same thing as is_integer(string). You also don't need to set the boolean bool_is_int because unless you actually want that value later in the program.

Comment: Thanks johnsoe, you helped out a lot.  Any no disrespect to anyone else; this was just the first answer I saw that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use an if/else statement.  The Ternary operator is useful when you you want to set a variable to one of two values based on a condition.  In your example, you don't want to set the value if the string is not an integer so ternary doesn't fit the situation well.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple :)

```
int field_num = isInt(string) ? Integer.parseInt(string) : Integer.MAX_VALUE;

if (field_num == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
     // error; string is not a valid representation of int
}
```

To determine Whether a `String` represents an `int` value :

```
public static boolean isInt(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Corrected]

Learn one thing at a time.

First, the  ?: operator (more often referred to as the conditional operator, or the if/else operator; "ternary" just means it takes three arguments, and it's the only C operator that does so, hence the confusion)...

```
field_num = is_integer(string) ? Integer.parseInt(string) : null;
```

Ahhh. So field_num is an Integer. Would have help if you'd said that.

Second: Assignment-in-passing. If you don't know that you need to do this, and you can't make it perfectly obvious what you're doing and why, DON'T. It's hard to read, and it's rarely appropriate.

Also, "int" is not a legal variable name.

But if you insist:

```
Integer myint;
boolean bool_is_int;
field_num = (bool_is_int = is_integer(string)) ? (myint = Integer.parseInt(string)) : null;
```

What's myint's value in the false/else case? It's left as whatever it had been set to previously. This might be what you intended, but it's very hard for someone reading your code to understand.

In most cases, unless the ?: is a very simple one that can be read at a glance -- `(foo!=null) ? foo.doSomething() : defaultValue` -- you're better off using a real if/then/else statement. It's likely to be just as efficient after the compiler and JIT are done with it, and it'll be a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: "Ahhh. So field_num is an Integer. Would have help if you'd said that."  <-- I did say that :P    Thanks for your answer, though. :)